# jQuery jplist: click events on rows not firing when initialized, sorted, selected

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

i have a google map which has a trigger on, by clicking a div class row. This is completely ignored when the jplist plugin is used on the page. If i remove the code for this plugin the trigger works perfectly.

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LVThH/

```
$(this).click(function(){
google.maps.event.trigger( otherMarkers ,'click');
});
```

I really want to get to the bottom of what the issue is here and if its a conflict.

Please help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that no one is noticing you ;) so I give you something to get along with - I tried it out and it seems that jplist might be unbinding your click events from those `.row` class div's (and all under it) - when its initialized, sorted, or what so ever. It provided also `redraw_callback` event but it fired only once when page had been loaded (what a shame, because it could be used to attach your own `.row` click events after initialization). To demonstrate something like: `redraw_callback: setClickEvents();` where `setClickEvents();` would be method which contains code similar to yours where you call marker click.

But since it didnt work! - I see at least few possibilities:

1.) (GOOD way) Try another plugin - since I already hate jplist for doing those unbindings or...

2.) (HACKER way) Add javascript click handlers to div while not using jquery and write a bit javascript to top of the page to call clicks for markers which are put inside array when map is initialized.

Try out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LVThH/9/) (tested to work with moz and chrome.) .. Notice that I would still choose either Good way or consulting plugin maker how `redraw_callback` works or is it broken etc etc.

Comment: You are a genious, and I am insanely grateful for your help. Really is very much appreciated. I am going to have to go with the hack as I have come this far with the plugin itself. I will put this forward to the writer of the plugin though as it is pretty annoying. Thanks again :)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261150/javascript-issue-google-maps-and-jplist-plugin :p

Comment: Dr.Molle, you are hilarous!